# Creating facet_wrap plots in for loop, identifying max for each facet

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, facet

MWE data:

```
qdat = data.frame(id = rep(c(rep("a",5), rep("b",5)),2),
                  month = as.factor(c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10))),
                  time = c(rep(1:5,4)),
                  score = c(12,23,34,45,56,
                            4,5,6,8,7,
                            11,22,33,55,44,
                            7,8,9,10,12))
```

I want to create a `facet_wrap` plot for each `id`, with the `month` as the individual facet. I want to label the `max` `score` for each `month` per `id`.

I can create the plots for each `id` as follows. However, this is only labelling the `max` `score` per `id` not for each `month` per `id`:

```
for (ID in unique(qdat$id)) {
  p = subset(qdat, id ==ID)
  
  ind = which(p$score == max(p$score))
  
  plot = ggplot(p, aes(x= time, y = score, colour = month))+
    geom_point()+
    labs(title = ID)+
    geom_text(data = p[unique(c(ind)),], aes(label = score))+
    facet_wrap(~month)
  print(plot)
}
```

[image: plot for id ==a]

[image: plot for id == b]

The plot for id ==a, should label 55 in month 2 and the plot for id==b, should label 8 in month 1, in addition to the labels already present.

**PS:**

The reason for using `ind` is because I'd also like to be able to label the points which are n rows above and below the max value e.g. `ind+1`. I appreciate this is an additional question, but would settle for an answer to main question

Answer (score 0):

I find it's easier when working with facets to extract the data beforehand, and add it later:

```
maxData <- qdat %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  slice_max(score)

  for (ID in unique(qdat$id)) {
    p = subset(qdat, id ==ID)
    
    ind = which(p$score == max(p$score))
    
    plot = ggplot(p, aes(x= time, y = score, colour = month))+
      geom_point()+
      labs(title = ID)+
      geom_text(data = maxData, aes(label = score)) +
      facet_wrap(~month) +
      theme_minimal()
    print(plot)
  }
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. However, it doesn't work for each `id` as you've selected the max per month. I want the max per id and per month. Adding `group_by(id, month)` doesn't work as it gives the maximum for each `id` for all plots. I've updated the data and added nuance.